# How to rollback transactions SQL Server Scripts?

Tags: sql-server, dbup

I am using DbUp ([Documentation](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) package to maintain and execute scripts on the database.
Currently, I am using

```
var builder = DeployChanges.To
                        .SqlDatabase(connectionString)
                        .WithExecutionTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300))
                        .WithTransactionPerScript()
                        .WithScriptsFromFileSystem(rootPath, new FileSystemScriptOptions { IncludeSubDirectories = true })
```

I want to rollback all the transactions if any scripts fails while executing a bunch of scripts.
Using,

```
WithTransactionAlwaysRollback()
```

Transaction rolls back even if the all the scripts execute successfully. I only want to rollback on failure.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.WithTransaction()
```

instead of

```
.WithTransactionPerScript()
```

And here's an implementation of these extension methods:

```cs
public static UpgradeEngineBuilder WithTransaction(this UpgradeEngineBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Configure(delegate (UpgradeConfiguration c)
    {
        c.ConnectionManager.TransactionMode = TransactionMode.SingleTransaction;
    });
    return builder;
}

public static UpgradeEngineBuilder WithTransactionPerScript(this UpgradeEngineBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Configure(delegate (UpgradeConfiguration c)
    {
        c.ConnectionManager.TransactionMode = TransactionMode.TransactionPerScript;
    });
    return builder;
}
```